# Jquery each function not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following json array which I passed through PHP.
PHP array is -

```
<?php 
    $arrTestData = [
    1 => [
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Written'
     ],
     2 => [
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Verbal'
     ]
    ];
   $arrVariable = json_encode( $arrTestData );?>
```

I am trying to iterate php array in javascript like this -

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var response = '<?php echo $arrVariable; ?>';
        data = $.parseJSON(response);

         $.each(data,function(key,value) {
            console.log(data.key + " --- " +data.value);
        });
</script>
```

If I print console for data it shows me but it's not getting worked inside a loop.
But in a console, it gives me **undefined**. I want the values which I get in an array.

Comment: May be var response = '<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $arrVariable); ?>';

Answer (score 0):

The response object, which is an array, is put into a variable named `data`. In your `$.each` function, you attempt to access the `.key` and `.value` items in the array. But arrays don't have those values.

What you *should* do here is use the *standalone variable names* the arguments to the `.each` callback has - that is, `key` and `value`. They aren't *properties* of `data`, they're standalone variables:

```
     $.each(data,function(key,value) {
        console.log(key + " --- " + value);
    });
```

Note that since the values are *objects*, this will result in

```
1 --- [object Object]
2 --- [object Object]
```

If you want to iterate over the inner object's *keys and values* as well, use `Object.entries`:

```
$.each(data,function(key,value) {
   Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, val]) => {
     console.log(key + ' --- ' + val);
   });
});
```

Output:

```
id --- 1
name --- Written
id --- 2
name --- Verbal
```

Also note that there's no need to require a big library like jQuery just to load a JSON. You can achieve all of this easily with vanilla JS alone:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const response = '<?php echo $arrVariable; ?>';
  const data = JSON.parse(response);
  Object.values(data).forEach((obj) => {
     Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
       console.log(key + ' --- ' + val);
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this and it works !!

```
for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(data[key]['id']);
                console.log(data[key]['name']);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. They are not very useful for learning about why the original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution -

```
$.each(data,function(key,value) {
            console.log(key + " --- " + value.id + " --- " + value.name);
        });
```